# Facebook Api V10 : How to tag or mention a user in my facebook post?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps, mention

In Facebook Api V10, what is the option for tagging or mentioning a user in my Facebook post. I have tried with @[username] but it just display like what I wrote in message. Also tried with @{[username]} but result is same. Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2):

You can only mention pages. User profiles are not allowed.

To mention a page use the format `@[page-id]`. Usernames will not resolve.

Here is some additional info: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/mentions/

Note, the Page being mentioned must allow Page tagging.

Answer (score 1):

You can use @[user_id],in case for page use @[page_id]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried @[{username}] ? :)